# In-App Purchase "Create" button is deactivated for iOS In app purchase creation

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I want to create my first in app purchase for my app in iTunes page. For that I have followed the following steps.

1. Checked my app id already as `In-App Purchase` enabled in developer account.

[image: Developer page for app id permission]

2. Move to itunesconnect.apple.com and move to my specific app and then moved to Features and In app purchase.

[image: In app purchase disabled]

3. I have seen my `In-App Purchase` "Create" button is disabled.

Can anyone help me why I am facing that kind of issue from apple?

Please note: I have already uploaded the app multiple times and apple rejected app multiple times as I have used the Paypal Subscription process for payment, they want us to implement the In-App Purchase instead subscription via Paypal. That is why I want to create the In-App Purchase for that app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below image their is different type of **IAP**[image]But in your case their is no option So this happens if you have not filled out the legal agreements for sales in iTunes Connect.For this You need to be logged into the account with the Legal permission in iTunes Connect. Then go to Agreements, Tax, and Banking. Then you need to create and fill out the Paid Applications contract which will include putting in your banking and tax info. Once you do that, the In App Purchase menu will have items in it.

Comment: Thanks, for me, accepting the new terms and condition in Agreements, Tax, and Banking Worked.